# Finding optimal calendar spreads and diagonals

Tags: options, backtesting, greeks, reference-request, option-strategies

I am looking for some pointers on risk/return profiles of calendar spreads and diagonals with different strikes and expiration dates, preferably based on historical backtests with SPY options.

Please post anything that might be helpful, be it blog posts, articles, papers, software/code (preferably R, but other programming languages are also ok).